# How to connect an NFS data store to Windows failover file server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, nfs, failovercluster

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to use a Windows failover file server as a front-end to my NFS file server to be able to utilize features such as DFS, shadow copy, etc.  Does it work that way?  It that even possible?  Or do I need to actually host the files off an NTFS storage to be able to utilize all the features available to a Windows file server?

The reason I want to do this is because we have a very fast and robust file server, but it's Linux-based, so it doesn't support all of the features I want out of a Windows file server.  I don't want to replace the file server, so I was hoping I could use Windows as a front-end.

Comment: You can use WSFC file services front end with a shared block back end (it's a pretty "classic" design for lots of deployments) but using file-over-file is a little bit tricky. Is it OK for you to store NFS shares as a block images or do you want Windows SMB3 and Linux NFS share same file content and permissions?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily create NFS shares with Failover cluster in your case. There even was a guide on that, a bit outdated, and you can skip the StarWind part and start with the CSV part, if you already have the shared storage.

Here's the link to the guide: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/configuring-ha-file-server-for-nfs-nas

Comment: you misread the question.  I updated the subject so it's less confusing - I can understand why you answered the way you did.